# Qt. How to handle double click event

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot to handle double click event. I try to do this using following code

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected slots:
    void OnDc(const QModelIndex&);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(const QModelIndex& )), this, SLOT(OnDc(const QModelIndex&)));
}

void MainWindow::OnDc(const QModelIndex&)
{
    ...
}
```

OnDc is not calling when double click happens.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use [void QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( QMouseEvent * event ) [virtual protected]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent)

You can override `QMainWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent`

```
void MainWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent( QMouseEvent * e )
{
    if ( e->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        ...
    }

    // You may have to call the parent's method for other cases
    QMainWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent( e );
}
```